# What's the difference between $(...) and `...`

Tags: bash, syntax

The question is as simple as stated in the title: What's the difference between the following two expressions?

```
$(...)
`...`
```

For example, are the two variables `test1` and `test2` different?

```
test1=$(ls)
test2=`ls`
```

Comment: @theman: thanks for the "insightful" comment.

Comment: Please note that this isn't just bash. This works in ksh and plain old sh (even in sh that's not bash in disguise).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The result is the same, but the newer $() syntax is far clearer and easier to read. At least doubly so when trying to nest. Nesting is not easy with the old syntax, but works fine with the new.

Compare:

```
$ echo $(ls $(pwd))
```

versus:

```
$ echo `ls \`pwd\``
```

You need to escape the embedded backticks, so it's quite a lot more complicated to both type and read.

According to [this page](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html), there is at least one minor difference in how they treat embedded double backslashes.

Comment: Nesting *is* possible using the backtick syntax, it just requires lots of backslashes and quickly becomes almost unreadable. Especially if you mix in other types of quotes.

Comment: @hobbs Thanks, I probably didn't realize. I've edited the answer.

Answer (score 5):

You might want to read `man bash`:

> When the old-style backquote form of substitution is used, backslash retains its literal meaning except when followed by $, `, or . The first backquote not preceded by a backslash terminates the command substitution.  When using the $(command) form, all characters between the parentheses make up the command; none are treated specially.

That's under the "Command Substitution" section of the manpage.

Answer (score 5):

Using ``` is the historical syntax, POSIX has adopted the now standard ` $(...) syntax.  See [Section 2.6.3](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/nframe.html)

Comment: Interesting. I always thought that the $( ) syntax was a pure bash addition (a very nice one, 'though).

Comment: I first saw it in ksh, back in 1992-or-so, before I'd used bash even once.

Comment: It's commonly thought that $() is bash specific, but that's because vim doesn't syntax highlight as per POSIX, rather using the orig shell syntax that _very_ few people code in today. To tell vim to use sensible syntax highlighting for shell scripts put this in your .vimrc

    let g:is_posix = 1

Comment: I think it did appear in ksh(1) first and adopted by POSIX afterwards.